# Linux Heap Fragmentation

Tags: c, linux, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, heap-fragmentation

I have a question that keeps bothering me for the last week.

In Windows debugger there is the `!heap -s` command that outputs the virtual memory's heap status and calculates the external fragmentation using the formula :

```
External fragmentation = 1 - (larget free block / total free size)
```

Is there a similar method in linux, that outputs those statistics needed to calculate the effect?

Long story now:
I have a C application that keeps allocating and deallocating space of different sizes, using malloc and free, each allocation has different life span.
The platform I am using is Lubuntu, so `ptmalloc2` algorithm is the default.

I am aware that those allocations are served in the virtual user space heap(except those that are larger than 128Kb, where the allocator uses `mmap`), and are mapped to physical pages when actually accessed .
The majority of the allocations is of size < 80 bytes, so they are served from FastBins.

Using `Valgrind` and `Massif` I can get the internal fragmentation, since it reports the extra bytes used for each allocation.

However, my main concern is how to figure out the external fragmentation. 
I am aware of the `/proc/[pid]/smaps` heap size and the `pmap-d[pid] anon` statistics, but I find it difficult to interpret them in terms of external fragmentation.

I am also aware of `LD_PRELOAD` , and I can dynamically connect the `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so`. This library outputs the heap total, peak and the distribution of the requested allocation sizes.

I know that `__malloc__hook` is deprecated now, and I do not really want to rely on implementation specific statistics like `malloc_stats()` and `mallinfo()` . However, If you have any suggestions using those two please let me know.

I can tell that the external fragmentation problem, is when a request can not be satisfied, because there is no contiguous space in the heap, but the requested total size is scattered all around that area.

I still have not figured out, how to get the statistics needed so I can calculate this effect. For example different formulas stating that I have to capture the `live_memory` or get the `total_free_pages`, or get the size of the `largest_free_block`. 
How can I have a function to "traverse" through the heap and gather those statistics?

Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if it is a problem, maybe you could use malloc to get a big chunk from the system and create a more specialized allocator for your data in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will depend on the allocator you are using.  That is, you would probably need a different strategy for whichever **malloc** (et al) and **free** implementation you are using.  If the implementation doesn't offer the information you seek as an extension, you will probably have to read its source-code and type your own logic to examine the state of allocations.

I believe that the mapping of pages to swap-space and physical RAM is at a lower level and so won't particularly help you in your goal.  The **malloc** (et al) and **free** implementation might or might not care about those lower-level details.

If you are certain that you are using **ptmalloc2**, are you able to find its source-code?